# Не работает js в Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, javascript

Друзья, первый раз делаю сайт на Drupal 7!

Короче, проблема в том, что сделал модельное окно с формой, а она работает только на главной странице!

Если перейти на любую внутреннюю, то ничего не работает! В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Традиционно напомню о существовании истории ревизий, из-за которых подобные редакции просто поднимают вопрос наверх, не более.

Comment: @Антон Созоненко, впредь воздержитесь от вандализма и бездумной замены текста и заголовка вопроса на случайные символы.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://development-ug.ru/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.once.js:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

jQuery не подключается в начале всех скриптов.
Там, где работает, там чуть выше подключается еще один jQuery.

Верстка у вас не валидная.

Comment: ну не знаю, загрузил файл jquery, все равно не работает...

Comment: Просто наймите спеца-фрилансера. Так будет дешевле, чем переписка тут.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!